# Intellij Idea can not create web application with version 2.5?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How can I create a web application with version 2.5?

The only option for creating web application is 3.1, but my tomcat does not support version 3.1.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @PedroLobito As it turns out, it is IntelliJ being buggy and confusing, so the question is actually okayish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to select version 2.5, you need to change the Java EE version to "Java EE 5". For some reason this doesn't update the servlet version dropdown list, and you first need to switch to another project type (eg Java) and then back to Java Enterprise to refresh the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

## You are in the wrong project type:

[image]

Comment: I've just checked with my copy of IntelliJ 2016.1, and in both cases I only have 3.1 listed. I can get 2.5 if I select JavaEE5 under Java Enterprise, and then select Java. After that I have the option both under Java Enterprise and under Java.